# passar indice selecionado de um hmtl para outro

Tags: angularjs

Boa tarde Srs.,

Tenho uma coleção que já é visível por dois html's distintos em minha app, no entanto no primeiro html eu percorro a coleção através de um ng-repeat e quando seleciono um determinado item desta lista, eu invoco o segundo html para apresentar apenas este item que foi selecionado. Então, o que eu preciso é: Passar para o segundo html o número do item que foi selecionado no primeiro html. Como eu faço isso? Já tentei com $rootScope, mas tive problema para usar $apply() que informa que já está em uso.

Comment: Cria um service pra isso, com as functions get/set

Comment: @DiegoAugusto, bom dia! já tenho um service que dispara uma promise e depois eu faço o set da coleção através de um controller que lê o retorno desta promise, mas para o get, que será necessário no segundo html, preciso informar qual item será recuperado neste get, este é o meu problema. Você tem como apresentar um exemplo de como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Você já tentou armazenar a referencia do indice em uma segunda variável e usar $scope (caso esteja no mesmo controller) ou $rootScope para informar ao segundo html qual elemento ele deve recuperar?

Comment: @Paz mesmo usando uma variável $rootScope para guardar o dado, este não é apresentado no segundo html. Tentei usar $scope.$apply() dai o sistema provoca um erro informando que $apply() já está em uso.

Comment: Apply é palavra reservada se não me engano, tente outro nome de variável

Comment: @Paz eu não declarei Apply, usei o recurso $scope.$apply() para atualizar o conteúdo das variáveis que sofreram alterações.

Comment: Alguma ideia nova?